# Qt Creator - write serial received data to UI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, serial-port

I'm working with qt creator and I want to get a QByteArray to the class that implements to UI, lets say class A. Class B implements a serial connection (RS232) and receives data in the following way:

```
QSerialPort::connect(serialport,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(SerialPortManager::GiveReceivedDataToUI()));
```

So in my method `SerialPortManager::GiveReceivedDataToUI(){}` I will read all the data from my serial connection like this: `serialport->readAll();` The data (stored in a QByteArray) is still in Class B. Now I want to get this data to a textbox in Class A.

I red some threads about accessing UI elements from a different class. Tried it with another connect, but I juist could figure out how to connect my data to a method in Class A(UI) that writes a textbox. I want to write it in decent OO, not just by making this public.

Any suggestions?

> UPDATE

```
class SerialPortManager : QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT
private:    
    static SerialPortManager* instance;    
protected:
    SerialPortManager();
public:
    static SerialPortManager* GetInstance();
    void OpenSerialConnection();
    void CloseSerialConnection();
    void WriteSingleACLCommand(QString);
    void WriteMultipleACLCommands();

public slots:
    void GiveReceivedDataToUI();
signals:
    void Send(QByteArray& s);

};
#endif // SERIALPORTMANAGER_H
```

Comment: "how to connect my data to a method in Class A(UI) that writes a textbox. I want to write it in decent OO" well, that IS decent oop. Do you want to store the data in the UI class as well?

Comment: @thuga, the thing with signals and slots in this particular issue is that I dont know what signal to use.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall it would be good to store it there as well, yes.

Comment: Well you would create your own signal in your `SerialPortManager` class. Use that to send the data to your own slot in the *Class A* class.

Comment: @thuga thankyou, did the following: `QWidget::connect(this, SIGNAL(Send(QByteArray&)), &a, SLOT(SerialReceived(QByteArray&)));` where **a** is the UI class. After the connect I emit the Send() signal. Which has my data.  Problem is: slot isnt executed..

Comment: Are you sure `a` is the correct `UI` class instance? In your snippet `a` seems to be a temporary instance. If you create the instances of *Class A* and *Class B* in `main`, you can establish the connection there. For good design, `SerialPortManager` should know nothing about your `UI` class. Also make sure you establish the connection only once.

Comment: Thanks, `a` was indeed a temporary instance. My SerialPortManager class knows nothing about the UI. The only problem is that my SerialPortManager class is a singleton, giving me this warning: `type cast : conversion from SerialPortManager* to const QObject exists, but is inaccessible` I'm calling the `GetInstance()`, so the singleton is being created.

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused as to why `SerialPortManager` is derived from `QMainWindow`, I'm going to assume you do actually use this class as your main window. But the problem is `class SerialPortManager : QMainWindow`. Here you derive privately from `QMainWindow`, you should derive publicly: `class SerialPortManager : public QMainWindow`. By the way, is there a reason as to why this class is a singleton class?

Comment: Thank you very much, its finally working. I'm using a singleton because of the serial connection, its connected to a PID controller, mainly for safety.

Comment: But do you actually display this class on your screen? Do you use any of the GUI features? If not, then you should be subclassing `QObject` instead of `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Best solution is Start in separate thread class which have to receive and send data to `RS232`, because in against case program can be freeze.  So use machanism `signal and slot` to this. In `Class A` You send `signal` to `Class B` with some command to RS323. `Class B`  received signal in slot and send to serial port some command  and next  receive data in `readyRead()`. When data will be ready `Class B` emited signal to `Class A` and  data will be received in `Class A` without any freeze.

Comment: @thuga no, the class isnt implementing any UI features, I changes it to `QObject`

Comment: @Mbded yes, the application does freeze while reading data, the only thing is that our singleton is for a single thread application. Multiple threads makes a singleton a little bit more challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this way. This is also only conception to communicates with class which is use to send and received data **SIGNAL and SLOT** using `QThread`. This is also safe because we can avoid freeze. (Untested code.)

```
        class SerialPortManager : QSerialPort
        {
        Q_OBJECT

        public:
        SerialPortManager();

        private slots:
        SLOT_ReciveData()

        // here slot which will be received command from difrent class
        public slots:
        void CommandFromMainWindow(QByteArray command); 

        // here signal which will be emited if data was be received
        signals:
        void SendToMainWindow(QByteArray s); 

        };

        /******SOURCE********/
        SerialPortManager:: SerialPortManager()
        {
    // here also all setup Your serial port

        // in this connection we will be received data. This happen also in diffrent thread, because this is a part signal which was be send from main window
        QObject::connect(this , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(SLOT_ReciveData()) , Qt::QueuedConnection);

}

// and slot to recived directly form Serial Port               
        void SerialPortManager::SLOT_ReciveData()
        {

                /************HERE WE GOT SOME DATA********/
        QByteArray buffer;

        while(this->bytesAvailable() > 0) // we read to time is data is available in buffer
        {
        buffer.append(this->readAll());

        }

        /******If any data is yet avaiable we send SIGNAL to mainwindow!!!!****/

        SendToMainWindow(buffer)

        }
```

MainWindowClass is Singelton

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
private:

QThread *threadCOM;
SerialPortManager *comconfigure;         

// From this signal we something send to Serial Port for example some command
signals:
void SIGNAL_To_SerialManager_LetMeSomeData(QByteArray cmd);

// And here we something received form Serial Port
public slots:
void SLOT_Yeah_I_Get_Data(QByteArray &s);

};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{

threadCOM = new QThread(this); // new thread for your class with serial port
comconfigure = new SerialPortManager();
comconfigure->moveToThread(threadCOM); // attachment particular thread to pinter Your class
threadCOM->start(QThread::HighestPriority); // and start, but wait for signal

// here connect signal form main windowd which send command to serial port
QObject::connect(this , SIGNAL(SIGNAL_To_SerialManager_GevMeSomeData(QByteArra);) , comconfigure , CommandFromMainWindow(QByteArray)))

// also connect signal to recived data to main window
QObject::connect(comconfigure , SIGNAL(SendToMainWindow(QByteArray)) , this, SLOT_Yeah_I_Get_Data(QByteArray)))

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate it.  I will give this a try in the next few days, will let you know how it worked out.

Comment: You just have to remember not to leave memory leaks. `comconfigure ` is never destroyed in your code. It is also a good idea to stop the thread correctly before exiting your application.

Comment: @thuga there is also another issue regarding the readyRead() signal, this signal is emitted whenever there is new data availiable, so the new data will directly be send to MainWindow. Is there a way to fill up the buffer until the sender is totally done writing (not using `waitForReadyRead`)?, by using `setReadBufferSize`?

Comment: `setReadBufferSize` won't help you. This just sets the maximum size of the buffer. You need to know the size of the data you're expecting to receive. After you get that amount of data, then you can send it to `MainWindow`.

Comment: @Pim why You do not use `bytesAvailable()` , as I writed above. Then data will be received to while in buffer something have. Try use something similar to `SLOT_ReciveData()` this slot is call after signal `readyRead()`

Comment: @thuga yes, that is the problem I dont know how big the data package is, it is a variable size.

Comment: @Mbded that isnt solving the problem because `readyRead()` is being called multiple times, so your buffer will be `== 0` multiple times. You will be exiting the while loop. This is because of that fact that our PID controller is sending a lot of data on our request. This causes the multiple callings of `readyRead()`

Comment: @Pim You will have to know. TCP will divide your data into chunks, so there is no way around it. Common way to find out this information, is to prepend the size of the data being sent to the beginning of the data you're about to send. The answer I linked to tells you this.

Comment: @Pim buffer will be empty only then device finished send data.  So readyRead() slot dosen't call multiple. Will be call only one, unlsess Your data is receives every few seconds.